# No se encuentra la 'variable' Firebase Android Studio / Firebase

Tags: android

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
public class NombreClase extends android.app.Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    }
}
```

Firebase tira el error

> Cannot resolve Symbol 'Firebase'.

Comment: Párese que falta un import y posiblemente una dependencia

Comment: Ok mirarè, serà la dependecia.

Comment: Fíjate en build.gradle a ver si la haz declarado

Comment: compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+' Me faltò. 
Gracias.

Comment: De nada! No olvides agregar la solución como respuesta así otros se benefician de este post. De paso puedes ganar algo de reputación. Saludos.

Comment: Listo, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay que agregar la dependencia en el archivo build.gradle del proyecto.

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
```

Sincronizan de nuevo y ya.
Así podràn importar la clase Firebase.

Comment: Victor marca tu pregunta como correcta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Depende del uso que quieras hacer de Firebase. Te recomiendo que sigas los pasos de la documentación de 
Firebase

Para registro de usuarios:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1
```

Para usar base de datos:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
```

Para almacenar archivos (imágenes, videos, audio):

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.6.1'
```